# How to filter extra context data from one serializer when used in another?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization

With django rest framework, I have two serializers for two different models. Lets say, the models are Author and Book. Author Model has the fields: name, address, phone, email, description and created_at while the book has the fields: name, publisher_name, genre, description, created_at and author(foreign key to Author model).

Now, I have the serializers defined for Author and Book:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ['created_at']

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    books = BookSerializer(many=True,required=False,null=True)        

    class Meta: 
        model = Author
        exclude = ['created_at']
```

The current schema gives the return of Book serializer for instance as:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Book_name",
    "publisher_name":"Publisher",
    "genre":"g",
    "description":"Book description",
    "author":1
}
```

While the return of authorserializer is:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "address":"Address",
    "phone":9812312312,
    "email":"email@email.c",
    "description":"this is description",
    "books": [
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"Book_name",
                "publisher_name":"Publisher",
                "genre":"g",
                "description":"Book description",
                "author":1
            }
            ]
    }
```

The thing is that I dont want all the details in the books of the return for Authorserializer, and want to exclude the description and genre.
How to do this?

Comment: just write another BookSerializer and exclude what you dont want and use in AuthorSerializer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new serializer for Books. Perhaps call it BookSummarySerializer:

```
class BookSummarySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ['created_at', 'description', 'genre']

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    books = BookSummarySerializer(many=True,required=False,null=True)        

    class Meta: 
        model = Author
        exclude = ['created_at']
```

Answer (score 0):

After having to define multiple serializers for the same model to be nested in different serializers, I came up with a simple dynamic model serializer that can be created inline where it is needed.

```
class InlineModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Used to dynamically create simple model serializers inline,
    mostly nested as fields in other serializers
    """

    def __init__(self, fields, model, **kwargs):
        """
        :param fields: The fields to be included
        :param model: The model class for the serializer
        :type fields: tuple
        """
        self.Meta = type('Meta', (), {'model': model, 'fields': fields})
        super(InlineModelSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

You can then use it in `AuthorSerializer` or wherever you need it like this:

```
books = InlineModelSerializer(
    model=Book,
    fields=('id', 'name'),
    many=True,
    required=False,
    allow_null=True
)
```

Of course this will not work if you have to override a method in the nested serializer, so it's mostly for simple use cases and not for complex writable nested serializers.

Hope this helps